# Unable to Retrieve Documents After Applying Query on Azure REST API via postman

Tags: postman, azure-cosmosdb

I am encountering an issue while performing a Cosmos query in Postman. Despite executing the same query successfully on Azure, Postman isn't retrieving any documents, as depicted in the attached screenshot.

[Postman Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oi38J.png)

**Header Information:**
[Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NW3Sm.png)

**Token Generation Code(Pre-request Script):**

```
var mastKey = postman.getEnvironmentVariable("CosmosDBMasterKey");
console.log("mastKey = " + mastKey);

var today = new Date();
var UTCstring = today.toUTCString();
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("RFC1123time", UTCstring);

var url = request.url.trim(); 

var strippedurl = url.replace(new RegExp('^https?://[^/]+/'),'/');

var strippedparts = strippedurl.split("/");
var truestrippedcount = (strippedparts.length - 1);

var resourceId = "";
var resType = "";

if (truestrippedcount % 2)
{
    resType = strippedparts[truestrippedcount];
   
    if (truestrippedcount > 1)
    {
        var lastPart = strippedurl.lastIndexOf("/");
        resourceId = strippedurl.substring(1,lastPart);
        console.log(resourceId);
    }
}
else 
{
    resType = strippedparts[truestrippedcount - 1];
    strippedurl = strippedurl.substring(1);
    resourceId = strippedurl;
}

var verb = request.method.toLowerCase();

var date = UTCstring.toLowerCase();

var key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(mastKey);
console.log("key = " + key);

var text = (verb || "").toLowerCase() + "\n" + 
               (resType || "").toLowerCase() + "\n" + 
               (resourceId || "") + "\n" + 
               (date || "").toLowerCase() + "\n" + 
               "" + "\n";
console.log("text = " + text);

// create the signature from build up request text
var signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(text, key);
console.log("sig = " + signature);

// back to base 64 bits
var base64Bits = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(signature);
console.log("base64bits = " + base64Bits);

// format our authentication token and URI encode it.
var MasterToken = "master";
var TokenVersion = "1.0";
auth = encodeURIComponent("type=" + MasterToken + "&ver=" + TokenVersion + "&sig=" + base64Bits);
console.log("auth = " + auth);

// set our auth token enviornmental variable.
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("authToken", auth);
```

Upon executing the query in Postman, I expect to receive a list of documents(object) matching the criteria specified in the query.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Have you tried by giving direct `masterKey` value instead of using `getEnvironmentVariable`?

Comment: Even after attempting with the direct master key, I'm still unable to retrieve the list of objects.

Comment: Nothing wrong in your code and i tried from my side too and faced few errors like version issue and it resolved after changing the version. I faced the same issue like above, only when the data which is to be retrieved is not present in the Cosmos DB container.